# Managing big Canon 7D files in Premiere CS5.5 with an average computer

Tags: video-editor, premiere

I'm new to editing and I'm trying to cope with a 7D project - very heavy files. Usually I don't have any problems with premiere and don't even have to render, but with these files, it's really difficult to get to the point when I CAN render, since I can't figure out which files should be on the timeline (playback is hardly working.)

Is there a way to render all of the footage? (not that many) Or maybe a better solution?

PC specs:

intel i7 2Ghz

4GB DDR3 memory

Nvidia GeForce GT 540M

Win 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a complete offline edit, it you want the quickest editing, use something like DV NTSC Quicktimes and edit on the fly, it will be SD but you never see the difference, then online to the original by replaceing footage back to your H.264...btw play around with your settings in Premiere and do some tutorials, there shouldnt be a reason an H264 file does not play on that system with those specs.  Transcoded is needed to play 5D or 7D footage within FCP but not within Premiere

Answer (score 1):

PCs don't like to deal with footage straight off the 7D. The best thing to do would be to transcode it using [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-win.html). I edit on a mac and use Prores 422 as my editing codec – I'm not too sure what you'd use for PC. Try MPEG-4 and see how that goes.

After you've converted all the footage, import it into Premiere and see if it runs smoother. If not, you may need to re-compress it at a lower quality so that your computer can handle it.

Good luck.

Comment: does this mean the final video will be of a lesser quality, or is there a way to export using the original files?

Comment: Yes, if you compressed it to a lower quality, the end result would be of lower quality than the raw footage. There may be a way to export using the original files but I've never had to do it. This kind of editing is called offline/online editing - you could try googling it.